# Echart bind different click event handler for different part of rich-text of xAxis.axisLabel in?

Tags: charts, echarts

[image: different click event handler for red and blue zone]

I need to bind click event handler for the icon in the red rectangle zone,bind  different click event handler for the blue rectangle zone.
right now ,i have no idea how to make it work, any help will be appreciate

[example and codes](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-rich-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out an solution.

You can add an icon dom after the label by manual, like below codes.

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

var option = {
  // your options
};

const parent = myChart.getDom().parentElement;
const xPixel = myChart.convertToPixel({ xAxisIndex: 0 }, 2) // to get the x postion of target category

var div = document.createElement('img')
div.style = `position: absolute;top: 366px;height: 12px;left:${xPixel + 2 * 14}px` // 2 * 14 is in order to correct the left 
div.src = 'image path'
div.addEventListener('click', () => {})

if (parent) parent.appendChild(div)
```

You can change `top` or `left` to correct the icon position.

If somebody have greater solution, plz let me know.